# How to extract elements from arraylist of objects which is having same category?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, collections

I have one table in sqlite database which contains five different columns as shown below.

```
CATEGORY    NOTE     DATE         PRICE       MODE
travel      delhi    10/5/2011    800          cash
food        daily    9/5/2011     500          cash
travel      goa       12/5/2011    1000         cash
```

The values in database are added by runtime from user. After all I retrieve it through content provider and store into an ArrayList and shown onto listview. But right now I want show it as per category means I want shown a category below that all its tasks then next category & its tasks like this. Item is class which contains all columnames as data members & its setter's and getter's. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Guava's [`MultiMaps.index`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method. It will create a MultiMap, i.e. a Map with categories as keys, and the list of items as values.

If you can't use Guava, then do what this method does:

- create a `Map<String, List<Item>>` where the key is the category
- iterate through the list of items, and place each item in the map

Here's an example:

```
Map<String, List<Item>> itemsByCategory = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Item>>();
for (Item item : theListOfItems) {
    String category = item.getCategory();
    List<Item> itemsOfCategory = itemsByCategory.get(category);
    if (itemsOfCategory == null) {
        itemsOfCategory = new ArrayList<Item>();
        itemsByCategory.put(category, itemsOfCategory);
    }
    itemsOfCategory.add(item);
}

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Item>> entry : itemsByCategory.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Category " + entry.getKey() + ":");
    for (Item item : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println("    Item : " + item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you give some example of code or tutorial for the second way which is understandable than first one in my point of view.

Comment: It's the  exact solution that I want. Thanks a lot,that worked fine for me............!!!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `GROUP BY` clause on category column to group your results according to category

Comment: Thanks for reply. But my query doesn't contain Group By clause. I am using  resolver.query(EXPENSE_URI, new String[]{ EXPENSE_CATEGORY,EXPENSE_DATE,EXPENSE_PRICE}, null, null,EXPENSE_CATEGORY); for getting values from database.

Answer (score 1):

Create a mapping class first -

```
class CategoryMapper
{
 String categoryName;
 ArrayList<User> usersForThisCategory;
}
```

Now, retrieve data from the database and add to the respective category mapper.

You can have another ArrayLis which will hold the number of categories and the items belonging to the category.

Comment: Thanks for reply.What is User here, can you plz explain.